# iskeyword with context

Tags: vi-words

In the Clean language, identifiers consist of *either all* 'normal' characters (`` [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_`]* ``) *or all* 'funky' characters (`[~!@#$%^&*-=+:<>,./?|]` and perhaps more). What I would like is a `iskeyword` setting that recognises this. To clarify some examples:

- `<.>` should be one word
- `x>y` should be split as `x`, `>`, `y`
- `x.y` should be split as `x`, `.`, `y`

Is it possible to write an `iskeyword` that does this properly? I have seen [this discussion](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Contextual-iskeyword-td1155687.html) where the end result seems to be it is not possible, but this is a slightly different use case and something might have changed  since 2006.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'iskeyword'` option defines the codepoints for a single keyword character, but cannot make a statement about its neighbors. In other words, you'd need a regular expression (something like `` [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_`]*\|[~!@#$%^&*-=+:<>,./?|]\+ ``), but Vim only offers a *set* of characters. Therefore, this still isn't possible. You have to pick either normal *or* funky characters, or live with the fact that a mixture of both that is not separated by whitespace is mistakenly recognized as a single keyword.